# ASP.Net MVC 5 Unobtrusive Client-Side Validation Inconsistent Behavior

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5, unobtrusive-validation

I am having strange behavior in regards to my ASP.Net MVC 5 applications that I am creating in regards to the unobtrusive client-side validation.

I have a created a complete new project, updated all Nuget Packages and created a very simple model with 3 fields that uses entity framework to connect to a sql database. The view was created automatically using the crud option when creating a view from a controller.

Basically what is happening is that the client-side validation is not working initially. All the fields in the model have been tagged with [Required] yet when I delete the value I receive no error message. The only error message I can trigger on the client side is with a date if I enter a letter. With an integer if I enter a letter I receive no client side validation.

Once I hit the submit button however, I receive the error messages. The submit button is not posting all the way back to the server. I have put breakpoints in the aplication on the HTTPPost and it is not reaching this which tells me that the client side validation is working.

Now where it gets strange is after I have hit the submit button, the unobtrusive client side validation begins to work for every element. All fields now become required and error messages update as intended. What could be causing this that when the application initially loads it does not work?

Comment: sounds like you aren't using client-side validation at all.  is `ClientValidationEnabled` set to true in your appSettings?

Comment: yes both that and unobtrusivejavascriptenabled are set to true!

Comment: This is normal behaviour from jQuery Validation plugin... http://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/#a-few-things-to-look-out-for-when-playing-around-with-the-demo (check point 2)

Comment: I guess I thought it would always validate...but now it seems after reading that it is working as intended. Thank you!